# How to find the last few commits to a git repository

Tags: git, commit

How to find the last few commits (say "20" commits) to a git repository. git log shows all the commits, I just need the last few commits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of ways, all of them documented in the `git-log` man page.

Specify a `-n` or `--max-count`:

```
$ git log -n 20
```

Or, specify a range of commits in the form of `<since>..<until>`:

```
$ git log HEAD~20..HEAD
```

You can omit the `<until>` since it's HEAD:

```
$ git log HEAD~20..
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of using `git log -n 20`, simply `gitk --all &` can see the structs and some detailed information.